# Why must an integrating sphere be a sphere?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, visible-light, scattering, instrument

Why must an [integrating sphere](http://www.labsphere.com/products/spheres-and-components/general-purpose-spheres/default.aspx) be a sphere? Why can't it be an integrating cube? What is the difference? Could I use a cube to measure total illuminance like an integrating sphere does?

[image]

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand, as it is unclear what you're asking. Can you phrase your question more clearly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surface coating of an integrating sphere is optimized for **low losses**. This white coating ([barium sulfate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barium_sulfate) or [PTFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytetrafluoroethylene)/Teflon) acts like an ideal lambertian scatterer.

[image: Lambertian scatterer]

- all light is scattered (Ok, not 100%, but a very high percentage like 99,5%. See ressources)
- it is emitted in the hemisphere following the cosine law: perpendicular to the surface it's highest. Intensity decrease follows a cosine law.

First generation stray light (blue in OP's picture) shows this light cone. Imagine this cone at the corner of a cube: some light will hit a wall again and suffers tiny losses. Detector port in cubic geometry hat a lower propability to  to be hit with the ray of highest energy. With a sphere however all surface normal **vectors point to its center**. Remember, that these rays "carry more energy" according to [Lambert's cosine law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_cosine_law). It will have lower losses than a measurement head with a cube geometry. A spherical geometry reduces the necessary number of stray events.

*Resources*

- Labsphere [Spectralon data sheet](http://www.labsphere.com/uploads/pb13025Targets.pdf): 99,5% hemispherical reflectance value: So 0,5% loss.

  - Spherical geometry is more expensive than cube geometry: [Stellarnet](http://stellarnet.us/integrating%20spheres.htm?gclid=CPuLzt-tzL0CFUTHtAodzFcAfA)
  - There also is a cylindrical geometry: [ILX Lightwave](http://www.newport.com/Optical-Power-and-Wavelength-Meter,-OMM-6810B/1009370/1033/info.aspx#tab_Literature) manuals

Answer (score 4):

In a sphere, any light emitted from the center will reflect off the sides at normal incidence come back to the center. In a cube, some rays never return to the center, so you aren't measuring all of the light emitted, which defeats the purpose of the device.